# Ruby on Rails: jQuery why is val not defined?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-1.3.2

```
function replaceIfEmpty(fieldID, value){
    alert($j('input#'+fieldID.val()));
    if ($j('input#'+fieldID).val() == ""){
        $j('input#'+fieldID).val(value);
    }
}
```

there's my function, and this is in my controller:

```
      page << "replaceIfEmpty('object_name', '#{t.name}');"
```

but when all this is invoked, an alert tells me:

```
RJS error:

TypeError: Object object_name has no method 'val'
```

even though I'm using jQuery 1.3.2, the docs say .val() isn't new to 1.4 =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parenthesis are a bit off, this:

```
alert($j('input#'+fieldID.val()));
```

Should be:

```
alert($j('input#'+fieldID).val());
```

Currently you're trying to call [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the string `fieldID`, rather than the jQuery object.

---

A bit of a tangent from the issue here:  *If* you upgrade to **1.4+** you can make this a bit shorter by passing a function to [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like this:

```
function replaceIfEmpty(fieldID, value){
  $j('#'+fieldID).val(function(i, oldVal) {
    alert(oldVal);
    return oldVal == "" ? value : oldValue;
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the 1.4 tip. Over teh next couple weeks I'm upgrading all the javascript, I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, it looks to me as though fieldID is not what you think it is. Have you debugged using Firebug at all?